# `cube` query performance issues with ordering

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-11, query-performance

I have a `cube` column named `embedding` in a `documents` table storing a vectorized (TF-IDF) representation of some text in the field which I converted into dense format. I created a GIST index on the 
But I am having trouble with query performance. It takes ~20 seconds on this query (~5MM rows on a 32GB machine):

```
select id 
from documents 
where embedding <-> cube('(0.08470847,...,0.06106149)') < 0.25 
order by embedding <-> cube('(0.08470847,...,0.06106149)') asc 
limit 25
```

The same query *without* the `order by` performs within milliseconds.

I am not sure how to improve the ordering performance.

I ran explain analyze on the query and this is the result:

```
Limit  (cost=0.54..323.63 rows=25 width=12) (actual time=18032.104..18704.827 rows=25 loops=1)
  ->  Index Scan using ix_100 on documents  (cost=0.54..22895274.16 rows=1771566 width=12) (actual time=18032.101..18704.797 rows=25 loops=1)
        Order By: (embedding <-> '(0.084708469999999994,... , 0.061061490000000003)'::cube)
        Filter: ((embedding <-> '(0.084708469999999994,... , 0.061061490000000003)'::cube) < '0.25'::double precision)
Planning Time: 1.575 ms
Execution Time: 18728.073 ms
```

I am at a loss how to proceed from here, I wish to avoid sorting after fetching the results in the application layer and ideally should work within the database.

Any ideas?

Edit: adding the explain(analyze,buffers) for the query with limit

query:

```
explain (analyze, buffers) 
select id 
from documents 
where embedding <-> cube('(0.08470847,..,0.06106149)') < 0.25 
limit 10;
```

with this output:

```
Limit  (cost=0.00..7.73 rows=10 width=4) (actual time=0.036..0.076 rows=10 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=5
  ->  Seq Scan on documents  (cost=0.00..1370989.16 rows=1772915 width=4) (actual time=0.034..0.072 rows=10 loops=1)
        Filter: ((embedding <-> '(0.084708469999999994..., 0.061061490000000003)'::cube) < '0.25'::double precision)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 10
        Buffers: shared hit=5
Planning Time: 0.107 ms
Execution Time: 0.098 ms
```

Edit -2 :

modified query per last update and results are back to ~20 secs per query

```
Limit  (cost=0.54..323.56 rows=25 width=12) (actual time=727.488..21603.571 rows=25 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared read=1352076
  ->  Index Scan using ix_100 on documents  (cost=0.54..22910761.65 rows=1773159 width=12) (actual time=727.485..21603.535 rows=25 loops=1)
        Order By: (embedding <-> '(0.0665496899999999947, ... 0.063358020000000001)'::cube)
        Filter: ((embedding <-> '(0.0665496899999999947, ... 0.063358020000000001)'::cube) < '0.25'::double precision)
        Buffers: shared read=1352076
Planning Time: 0.164 ms
Execution Time: 21644.516 ms
```

Comment: How many dimensions are in your cube?

Comment: @jjanes it has 100 dimensions.

Comment: At 100 dimensions, you are not likely to find a general solution which is much better than just scanning the table and sorting the results.  If you have at least 25 results very close to your query cube, perhaps it will be a lot better; but that won't generalize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorting works on values the query returns.

Here you have an index on embedding column but you are sorting on the result of `embedding <-> cube('(0.08470847,...,0.06106149)')`, which is not indexed.

So first retrieve the required result with the help of sub-query, then perform sorting.

```
select id,EDistance
from
(
select id, embedding <-> cube('(0.08470847,...,0.06106149)') EDistance 
from documents 
where embedding <-> cube('(0.08470847,...,0.06106149)') < 0.25
limit 25
) t
order by EDistance ASC
```

Thanks!

Comment: @RichardHuxton was right, i was seeing some 25 random results. so I modified to the updated query and it's gone right back to ~20 seconds query time. I have updated my question to show the explain analyze results :-/

Comment: @Santino Instead of limit use `FETCH FIRST 25 ROW ONLY;`

Comment: unfortunately no luck with `fetch first...` still takes 20 secs